# How can I improve this update?

Tags: sql-server, performance, spatial

I'm working with SQL Server 2014 Express edition and I want to upload some OpenStreetMaps data.

Data is a 172 Mb XML and it loads ok. The problem is with this script:

```
UPDATE ways
SET geog4326 = 'LINESTRING(' + STUFF((
SELECT ',' + CAST(CAST(n.Longitude AS decimal(18,9)) AS varchar(32)) + ' ' + CAST(CAST(n.Latitude AS decimal(18,9)) AS varchar(32)) AS [text()]
FROM
ways w JOIN waynodes wn ON w.wayid = wn.wayid
JOIN nodes n ON wn.nodeid = n.nodeid
WHERE wn.wayid = w.wayid
ORDER BY w.wayid, orderid
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('/', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') +')'
```

I get an .NET framework Out of memory on SQL Server Management Studio and also running it from SQLCMD.
`ways` table has 101,393 rows and `waynodes` has 1,018,575 rows.

Do you know how can I improve this script?

By the way, I get this script from this [tutorial](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/loading-open-street-map-data-in-sql-server-part-ii-ways/).

I have no index and no plan execution. I'm only following the tutorial and I get out of memory error.

Comment: The `UPDATE wins SET ...` should probably be changed to `UPDATE w SET ...`  as well.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks for your comments but if I change `UPDATE ways SET ...` with `UPDATE w SET...` I get an invalid object error in `w`.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Invalid object error in `w` object.

Comment: Oh, I misread. The `UPDATE` statement has no `FROM`. The `FROM` is inside the `STUFF()`, but seems like it is a un-correlated subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ypercube said in his comment you seem to have an uncorrelated subquery.  This means that for each way you are trying to build a line containing 1,000,000 odd nodes.

Also it it would be best to put a Geography constructor around the result of the subquery.

The tutorial's update statement that you referenced has got a correlated subquery, because the `WHERE` clause is `wn.wayid = ways.wayid` 
Changing your update query to this should fix the issue.

```
UPDATE ways
SET geog4326 = Geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(' + STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + 
        CAST(CAST(n.Longitude AS decimal(18,9)) AS varchar(32)) + ' ' + 
        CAST(CAST(n.Latitude AS decimal(18,9)) AS varchar(32)) AS [text()]
    FROM ways w 
        JOIN waynodes wn ON w.wayid = wn.wayid
        JOIN nodes n ON wn.nodeid = n.nodeid
    WHERE wn.wayid = ways.wayid -- Changed to ways to correlate
    ORDER BY w.wayid, orderid
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('/', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') +')',4326)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM waynodes wg WHERE ways.wayid = wg.wayid GROUP BY wg.wayid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Personally I prefer to construct my update statements similar to the following.

```
UPDATE z
SET geog4326 = Geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(' + STUFF(CAST(x.linestring AS VARCHAR(MAX)),1,1,'') +')',4326)
FROM ways z
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT ',' + 
            CAST(CAST(n.Longitude AS decimal(18,9)) AS varchar(32)) + ' ' + 
            CAST(CAST(n.Latitude AS decimal(18,9)) AS varchar(32)) AS [text()]
        FROM ways w 
            JOIN waynodes wn ON w.wayid = wn.wayid
            JOIN nodes n ON wn.nodeid = n.nodeid
        WHERE z.wayid = w.wayid 
        ORDER BY w.wayid, orderid
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) x (linestring)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM waynodes wg WHERE z.wayid = wg.wayid GROUP BY wg.wayid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

I've tested a SELECT version of my update on some made up data.
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1400/0)

```
 WITH ways AS (
 SELECT *
 FROM (VALUES
    (1),(2),(3)
    ) W(wayid)
 ), 
 waynodes AS (
 SELECT *
 FROM (VALUES
    (1,1,1),
    (1,2,2),
    (1,3,3),
    (2,1,4),
    (2,2,5),
    (2,3,6),
    (3,1,7),
    (3,2,8)
    ) WN(wayid, orderid, nodeid)
 ), 
 nodes AS (
 SELECT *
 FROM (VALUES
    (1, 0, 0),
    (2, .1, 0),
    (3, .1, .1),
    (4, .1, .1),
    (5, .2, 0),
    (6, .3, 0),
    (7, 0, 0),
    (8, 0, .2)
    ) N(nodeid, longitude, latitude)
 )
SELECT Geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(' + STUFF(x.linestring,1,1,'') +')',4326)
FROM ways z
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT ',' + CAST(CAST(n.Longitude AS decimal(18,9)) AS varchar(32)) + ' ' + CAST(CAST(n.Latitude AS decimal(18,9)) AS varchar(32)) AS [text()]
        FROM ways w 
            JOIN waynodes wn ON w.wayid = wn.wayid
            JOIN nodes n ON wn.nodeid = n.nodeid
        WHERE z.wayid = w.wayid 
        ORDER BY w.wayid, orderid
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) x(linestring)
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. I have tried the first script and I get this error: `The LineString input is not valid because it does not have enough points. A LineString must have at least two points.`. And the second script show this error: `The type of xml data argument is invalid for argument 1 of stuff function.`. I will continue working on yours script to see if I can fix this errors. Thanks again.

Comment: I've made a couple of edits to fix things up and run a small test.  The two points error is interesting.  That would indicate the data has ways with 0 or 1 nodes.

Comment: @VansFannel Can you do a quick test on the waynodes table to insure each way has more than one node.  `SELECT wayid, MAX(order), COUNT(*) FROM waynodes GROUP BY wayid HAVING COUNT(*) < 2`

Comment: I have changed the sql to get all linestrings and some of then have this format: `LINESTRING(-0.323366500 39.503936800)`. How can avoid `LINESTRING` with only one point?

Comment: Here http://pastebin.com/NJmCJQn6 I have pasted the result in CSV format.

Comment: @VansFannel That's a lot of single node ways.  I'll make a edit to the answer to filter them out in each of the update statements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now but the data is really bad. I will ask OpenStreetMap managers to see if there is a better data for Barcelona.

Comment: @VansFannel  glad to help